# Any official (government) sources for standardized tables or charts for English-to-Russian transliteration?

Tags: транслитерация, алфавит

Does anyone have a link to an official Russian or American/UK (government) source of some charts/tables that standardize transliteration of Cyrillic (Russian in particular) letters to Roman (English) letters?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! We try to avoid link-only answers and questions that ask for link-only answers. If you can read Russian, this Wikipedia article would be a good starting point for your research: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9. Thanks!

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/english-equivalent-of-%d0%b9